# Connect Vector3[] with mesh in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

In my Unity3d project, I want to create a mesh that connects four spheres.

I created a new quad and assigned the array of `transform.position` from my four speheres to `GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertecies` of my quad.

Since that does not work,
how can I **read or write** the **global position of a vertex** in Unity?

**MY SOLUTION (works)**

```
GameObject quad;
Transform[] spheres;
//asign values and do other stuff

void UpdateMesh(){
    Vector3[] newVerts = new Vector3[spheres.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < newVerts.Length; i++){
        newVerts[i] = spheres[i].position - quad.transform.position;
    }
    quad.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.vertecies = newVerts;
}
```

Comment: I cannot test this out right now, but I think you should call `RecalculateBounds()` on your mesh after changing the vertices.

Comment: You'd have to show some more code but one thing already, if you get the array and change the values, they won't affect the original as Unity copies the whole vertex array into a new array. So after modifying you'd have to assign the array back into mesh.vertices. This is because mesh is stored on C++ side and no bridge is created. just a copy of it.

Comment: one thing worth mentioning is you can use particle systems too. particle system has an option to use vertices of a mesh as emitting points. not sure how well this suites your situation, just saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on how you are assigning vertices.
Here is a working example you can experiment with, just attach this as a script to your quad:

```
using UnityEngine;

// adding ExecuteInEditMode attribute so we can easily see the results from the editor
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class VertexChanger : MonoBehaviour {

    // assign these from the editor
    public Transform Sphere0;
    public Transform Sphere1;
    public Transform Sphere2;
    public Transform Sphere3;

    // doing changes in update so we see this immediately from the editor
    void Update () {
        if (Sphere0 == null || Sphere1 == null || Sphere2 == null || Sphere3 == null) {
            return;
        } 
        // create a new array of vertices and assign it
        Vector3[] newVertices = new[] {
            Sphere0.transform.position,
            Sphere1.transform.position,
            Sphere2.transform.position,
            Sphere3.transform.position
        };
        MeshFilter meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        meshFilter.sharedMesh.vertices = newVertices;

        // these calls are not strictly necessary here...
        meshFilter.mesh.RecalculateBounds();
        meshFilter.mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
```

Please note that this will work as you expect only if you set the spheres in the right order, otherwise you might also need to recalculate the triangles array of the mesh.

Comment: Wow - great! Thanks! I solved it myself using a different apporach. Since the position of the vertecies is relative to `transform.position` of the gameObject, I calculated the new relative position by subtracting `gameObject.transform.position` from `spheres[n].transform.position`.

Comment: Ah, well, of course my solution works only if your quad is at position 0 and is not rotated, otherwise you'll see some funny stuff :)